# Open file with vim but keep the terminal open as well?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to open a new vim file in basically a new terminal window(urxvt) ?

For example if I am currently in ~/X/Y.txt and I write
vim --new-window(basically the command needed to open a new window) Y.txt

I still want my current urxvt session while opening the Y.txt in a vim-Session.

Comment: What makes you think your shell session is gone? You can `<C-z>` to it at any time.

Comment: I know that's it's not gone but I would like to keep it open and useable after opening with vim

Answer (score 0):

`gvim` will open up vim in a GUI (i.e., not in the terminal).

Comment: I don't think people understand your use case enough to be able to advise you on the best solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim's [client-server](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html) model. Run one instance as a server and edit files with option `--remote`.

Another solution would be to use terminal multiplexors like [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), tmux or such.

Other variants are: use a terminal with tabs, use gvim.

Answer (score 0):

I highly, highly, strongly recommend downloading [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree). It makes your Vim terminal look (relatively, comparatively) similar to a "normal" IDE, with a narrow file-and-folder bar on the left side, and a "main" terminal window taking up the rest of the screen. You use Ctrl+W to navigate back and forth between the two screens. Plus, in the sidebar, you can use normal Vim commands to move up and down. Whoever created that plugin put a lot of work into it.